# Can I increase the compution speed of correlation analysis between vast time-series data?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, correlation

First, I'll introduce my target and my code to achieve it

1. *VALUE* is a 3-d numpy array representing the time-variation of 2-d area. 
   (For example `value[:1000,2,3] = list` [the grid (X = 3, Y = 2)'s value from 0 to 1000s].)

   > In my real work, *VALUE*  is in the shape of (2812, 75, 90) ps:"2812" is the sum hour for 4 months
2. some point I called *SELECT* represents an interesting point which I'll do correlation analysis with every grid in the area.

   > SELECT is a pandas dataframe including each interesting point's X and Y
3. *COV* is  a 3-d array as a count matrix record the correlation level of each *SELECT* point with each grid point

   > Setting cut-off Pearson coefficient rc = 0.75,
   >   for *SELECT* point *t*,
   >   If r(i,j) > rc ==> cov[t,i,j] = 1, else cov[t,i,j] = 0

Here is my code, but it's kind of slow. I think some part of the process can be improved:

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
### SELECT is a pandas dataframe including each interesting point's X and Y
cov = np.zeros(len(SELECT)*VALUE.shape[1]*VALUE.shape[2]).reshape(len(SELECT), VALUE.shape[1],VALUE.shape[2])
for t in range(0,len(SELECT),1):
    select_grid = pd.DataFrame(VALUE[:,SELECT.Y.iloc[t],SELECT.X.iloc[t]])
for i in range(0,VALUE.shape[1],1):
    for j in range(0,VALUE.shape[2],1):
        data_grid = pd.DataFrame(VALUE[:,i,j])
         ## Using corr to compute the correlation r
        r_sg  = select_grid[0].corr(data_grid[0])
        if r_sg > 0.75:
            cov[t,i,j] = 1

end = timeit.default_timer()                
print end - start
```

Comment: Have you tried to run a profiler to see where the time is spent? For example `line_profiler` as described in [this article](https://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis), just scroll down to the "Line-by-line...." section. Might help shed some light on what can be improved.

Comment: Can you give the  magnitude of `len(SELECT), VALUE.shape[1],  VALUE.shape[2]` and `end - start`  to estimate possible improvement ? What is  `ds_grid` ? A link on data is also always a good tool.

Comment: Thanks! I havn't known about `timing context manager`. I'll learn it if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your job is time consuming :  roughly one second for each sample in SELECT.

- Vectorizing will not give you a big improvement, because the time consuming corr function is in the inner loop.
- You can however have a more light code, pandas is not strictly necessary here. As an exemple:

  ```
  VALUE=random((2812,5,5))
  select=pd.DataFrame(randint(0,5,(10,2)))
  ....
  for (x,y) in select.values:
  ....
       r=np.corrcoef(VALUE[:,x,y],VALUE[:,i,j])[0,1]
  ....
  ```

`[0,1]` is for selecting `r` here, because corrcoef compute a 2x2 array.

- The first optimisation you can do is working with numpy array rather than DataFrames for a 2x gain for the corr computation.

  ```
  DFexample = pd.DataFrame(VALUE[:,0,:])

  In [19]: %timeit np.corrcoef(VALUE[:,0,0],VALUE[:,0,1]) 
  1000 loops, best of 3: 556 µs per loop

  In [20]: %timeit DFexample[0].corr(DFexample[1])
  1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
  ```
- An other is to pre-compute means ans std, since `r(x,y) = (<xy>-<x><y>)/σx/σy` for a 3x gain :

  ```
  In [24]: s=VALUE.std(axis=0)  # 1 second

  In [25]: m=VALUE.mean(axis=0) # 2 second

  In [26]: %timeit ((VALUE[:,0,0]*VALUE[:,0,1]).mean() -m[0,1]*m[0,0])/s[0,0]/s[0,1]
  10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop

  In [31]: allclose(((VALUE[:,0,0]*VALUE[:,0,1]).mean() -m[0,1]*m[0,0])/s[0,0]/s[0,1],\
  DFexample[0].corr(DFexample[1]))
  Out[31]: True
  ```

**So you can win  at least a 6x factor**.